# EclipseLink or Derby throws exception at unexpected line

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I'm trying to execute insert/update and commit in derby thru eclipselink (JPA). I'm getting the following exception during execution.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Precision exceeds 31 digits!
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Utils.computeBigDecimalPrecision(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementRequest.computeProtocolTypesAndLengths(Unknown Source)
    ..
    ..
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:788)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:863)
   ..
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:430)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:714)
   at com.rw.util.RWCommonFactory.getCommonCodeSet(RWCommonFactory.java:194)
   at com.rw.what.RWTransaction.setProcessedStatusCode(RWTransaction.java:218)
```

RWCommonFactory.getCommonCodeSet contains

```
public RWCommonCodeSet getCommonCodeSet(String name, String value){
 Query query = manager.createNamedQuery(RWCommonCodeSet.FIND_CODE_NAME_CODE_VALUE);
 query.setParameter("codeName", name.trim());
 query.setParameter("codeValue", value.trim());
 List l = query.getResultList();
 if(l.isEmpty()){
    return null;
 }
 else{
    return (RWCommonCodeSet) l.get(0);
 }
 }
```

**RWCommonCodeSet** is an entity table that doesn't contain any decimal columns, But getting precision exceeds exception here.

Also in this execution I do persist some other entities that contains **DECIMAL(31,5)** columns.

I tried enabling Derby log and Eclipse link log but I couldn't get right error from that log.

How can I get actual error location.

Thanks.

Comment: vels4j, have you found the source of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your query. I think, For `Unknown Source`, your entity does not use `@Entity`, don't configure in `persistence.xml`.

Comment: here is my named query `@NamedQuery(name = RWCodeSet.FIND_CODE_NAME_CODE_VALUE, query = "SELECT r FROM RWCodeSet r WHERE r.codeName = :codeName and r.codeValue=:codeValue")`. Here both codename and codevalue are String data type

Comment: Seems u've entirely edited your previous answer, anyway this is not an annotation or persistence configuration error. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I traced it. I had DECIMAL(10,3) in database and tried to persist BigDecimal occasionally initialized from double. I had

```
new BigDecimal(2006.3)
```

instead of

```
new BigDecimal("2006.3")
```

The first one apparently doesn't fit into DECIMAL(10,3).